# selenium - select dropdown. Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am not able to select dropdown option using below code. This code returns error as element not located. Please assist. Thanks!!

```
    WebElement mySelectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("incident.severity"));
    Select dropdown= new Select(mySelectElement);
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("3 - Medium");
```

> Exception in thread "Thread-2"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"incident.severity"}

Below is the dropdown screenshot and corresponding code.

[image: field screenshot]

```html
<div class="form-group " style="" id="element.incident.severity">
 <div nowrap="true" data-type="label" id="label.incident.severity" 
      type="choice" choice="3" class="foreign">
 <label dir="ltr" class=" col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label" 
       onclick="return labelClicked(this);" for="incident.severity"><span 
      id="status.incident.severity" title="" mandatory="false" aria-label="" 
     class=" label_description" oclass="" data-original-title=""></span>
<span title="" class="label-text" data-html="false" data-original-
title="">Severity</span></label></div>
  
<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 form-field input_controls">
<input name="sys_original.incident.severity" 
       id="sys_original.incident.severity" type="hidden" value="4">
<select style="direction:ltr; " id="incident.severity" 
      onchange="onChange('incident.severity');" class="form-control" ng-non-
      bindable="true" name="incident.severity" mandatory="false">
        <option value="1">1 - Critical</option>
        <option value="2">2 - High</option>
        <option value="3">3 - Medium</option>
        <option value="4" selected="SELECTED">4 - Low</option>
</select></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-lg-2 form-field-addons"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which binding? Java or Python or Ruby? Thanks

Comment: I am trying to use selenium webdriver using Java.

Comment: Probable the reason is the HTML DOM you have pasted is of `type="hidden"`. You must be having another Select tag. Thanks

Comment: No, this is visible as I gave in screenshot. This is the only tag for selecting the field.

Comment: try `dropdown.selectByValue("3");`

Comment: This is errored out in the first line itself. It is not able to locate the element. 
     driver.findElement(By.id("incident.severity"));

Answer (score 0):

***NoSuchElementException*** occurs when the driver is not able to find the webelement in the DOM of the webpage.

One of the reason for such error is your page is not completely loaded and you are trying to find that webelement, try to wait for sometime before you search for the webelement. For the Wait you can use *"Implicit wait"*.

**Sample code:**

```
//Initializing a WebDriverWait instance with a wait time of 30 seconds.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30); 

//This code will wait till 30 seconds(Maximum) before throwing the exception.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("incident.severity")));

WebElement mySelectElement = driver.findElement(By.name("incident.severity"));
```

Let me know if this helps.